# How can a system outside of Azure access a specific folder within a container on ADLS Gen2?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Unable to grant access (Read/Write) to a specific folder within an ADLS Gen2 container

As you can see in the screenshot below, I would need to GRANT a system/user outside of Azure Read/Write access to only this folder, and nothing else within the parent container.

[Folder I need to grant access to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FE0dX.png)

The solution would have been easy if I wanted to grant access to a specific container (For example datafactory), but since my requirement is to grant access to a specific folder (Test/Inbound/Bauer_Test/AsRun/Landing) within a container (datafactory), there is no way around it. I see SFTP as an option, but this is not feasible for my client. Please let me know if you have any advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to give access to particular folder within the container in ADLS gen 2.

**Primary Method:**

Add external user to Active directory by following this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/b2b-quickstart-add-guest-users-portal).
Select the folder and click on context menu select `Manage ACL`.

[image]

In the Access permission tab click on Add service principal to select the guest user to give control of access

[image]

Add the service principal and give the permissions regarding to your requirement and click on save button

[image]

**Secondary Method:**

you can generate SAS token at folder level by Selecting the folder and click on context menu selecting `Generate sas` option.

[image]

provide required permission according to requirements and click `Generate SAS token and URL`

[image]

SAS token will generate. Share with the external user. It will access to the folder. But as per my knowledge it is not secure method when comparing with above.